# Узнать какие признаки у объектов одного кластера на R

Tags: машинное-обучение, r, cluster

У меня построена модель KCCA на языке R. Ниже представлен код:

```
fc_cont <- new ("flexclustControl") 
fc_cont@tolerance <- 0.1            
fc_cont@iter.max <- 30              
fc_cont@verbose <- 1                
fc_family <- "ejaccard"
k <- 11
numCores = 11

kcca_clusters <- function(x, k, control) {
cl2 <- flexclust::kcca(x, k, family=kccaFamily("ejaccard"), weights=NULL, control=fc_cont, simple=FALSE, save.data=TRUE) 
return(cl2)
}
registerDoMC(numCores)
cluster <- foreach(k=2:30, .packages = "flexclust", .combine='c', 
               .export= c('tarin', 'fc_cont')) %dopar% kcca_clusters(train, k, fc_cont)
```

Мне нужно получить признаки объектов каждого кластера. Т.е. название признаков, которыми обладают объекты, попавшие в каждый кластер.

Пробовала

```
str(cluster)
```

выводит полную информацию, но не понятно как ее читать.

Comment: непонятно, что именно вы спрашиваете: как читать или как получить.

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом примере кода отсутствует объект `train`. Таким образом, код не является воспроизводимым.

Согласно примеру из справки на выходе `flexclust::kcca` получается S4 объект. Поскольку вы используете `foreach` с комбинацией через `c`, то `cluster` у вас должен быть типа `list`.

Если я правильно понял, то из объекта `kcca` вам необходимо извлечь слот `clusinfo`. Сделать это можно с помощью функции `slot`. Поскольку у вас список S4 объектов, то необходимо применить эту функцию к каждому из них.

```r
# k из цикла
k <- 2:30
names(res) = k
res <- lapply(cluster, slot, name = "clusinfo")
data.table::rbindlist(res, idcol = "k")
```

Пример из справки:

```r
data("Nclus")
cl4 <- kcca(Nclus, k=4)
cl2 <- kcca(Nclus, k=2)
res <- c(cl4, cl2)
res <- lapply(res, slot, name = "clusinfo")
data.table::rbindlist(res, idcol = "k")
```

Результат:

```r
   k size  av_dist max_dist separation
1: 1  109 1.408164 3.183290   3.296170
2: 1   85 1.196240 2.952339   1.286494
3: 1  291 2.808830 6.533686   3.210227
4: 1   65 1.202351 3.178317   1.309621
5: 2  102 1.623327 5.521410   4.962045
6: 2  448 3.598871 7.876550   4.717321
```